# Opening a video using link from local directory in PHP and html

Tags: php, html

Here is my code to open a video from local directory, the videos are correctly listed but when I click them nothing happens.....can some one help please

```
<?php

$directory = "C:/xampp/htdocs/vu/uploads/";

$phpfiles = glob($directory . "*.mp4");

foreach($phpfiles as $phpfile)
{echo "<li><a href=\"$phpfile\" target=\"_blank\" onClick=\"play()\">". basename($phpfile). "</a><li>";

}?>
```

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: Please add the code instead of using image

Comment: Ok I will asap..

Comment: I have added the code...

Comment: Could you also post the generated html?

Comment: How to do that I have no idea sorry

Comment: @lala_ray use the View Source feature in your browser to get the finished HTML that was actually created by the PHP.

Comment: The value of whatever is in the "href" attribute must be a URL (i.e. `http://www.example.com/myfile`), it cannot be a path on disk (e.g. `C:\files\myfile`) because that's not addressable by the web browser. You can't use a browser to fetch a file on a remote computer using the name of the file on disk, because, for security reasons, you don't know the structure of the remote computer's disk (even if you're running from "localhost" the browser treats it just like a remote computer). All you can get is what is exposed by the webserver via URLs.

Comment: Thank you @ADyson for the clarification but is there any other way I can achieve the same task i.e; Display all videos in a perticular directory and open them in an custom html page???

Comment: Put them in a folder on the server that the webserver can see, then you can write some PHP to list all the files in the folder and generate hyperlinks to them. And then write some javascript that will alter the "src" of a video player control on the page, whenever the user clicks on a listed file, so that the video will be played (assuming it's in a compatible format. If not the user would have to download it to their machine instead).